# How streams behave when flutter app transitions between AppLifecycleStates?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, lifecycle

When a flutter app transitions to `inactive`, `detached` or `paused` it may have active stream subscriptions. What happens to these subscriptions when the app moves between those states? Should I take care of cancelling/restarting subscriptions when transitioning into particular states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you want to pause a `Stream` while your app is `inactive` or `paused`.

Changing the ApplifeCycle state do not pause a stream subscription when changing state, and do only cancel subscription when you close your app, if you mention it in `dispose()` method.

You can try this code to test the behavior :

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  StreamSubscription sub;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    print(state);
    print('Paused: ${sub.isPaused}');

    // Here you can cancel or pause subscriptions if necessary
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      sub.pause();
    }

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    sub = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1))
        .listen(print);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    sub.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox();
  }
}
```